# Bootstrap dropdown based on content of MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap, PHP and MySQL, how do I populate a dropdown selection based on the contents of a mysql table.

For example I have a table user.
tblUsers
- id
- name
- email

How would a simple example of the PHP and HTML code look?

Comment: What you tried so far ? some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?PHP
$yourquery = (select id, name from tblUsers);

echo '<select>';
foreach($yourquery as $qry){
echo '<option value="'.$qry->id.'">'.$qry->name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

?>
```

Comment: Using the above is it possible to save the results and use them as a basis for a second dropdown.?

Comment: Yes you can use.
see this examples
http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-php.html

https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/select-box-change-dependent-options-dynamically